# Rails capistrano deploy to multiple servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I am trying to optimize my application. I would like to deploy my rails application to different machines. Unfortunately I can't understand how to do it.

```
role :web, "ip1","ip2"
role :app, "ip1, ip2"
role :db, "db_ip", primary: true
set :application, "Name"
set :user, "root"
set :port, 22
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
ssh_options[:keys] = %w(~/.ssh/id_key)
```

This is my configuration. I have two unicorn servers and one db server. When I use cap:deploy:cold it asks me for password but I can't understand the password of which machine I should enter? It doesn't work with all of the server's passwords. I receive

```
(Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: root)
```

Can someone explain me how should my configuration looks to be able to deploy to all of the machines?

Comment: are you really deploying as root?  Please please please rethink that. Run all your apps as no privileged users.

Comment: I can login to the machine with ssh root@ip. I see that my user there is /home/debian but even if I change it to 'debian', it doesn't work too. Also I am not able to login with ssh debian@ip.

Comment: which version of capistrano are you using

Comment: My current version is 2.15.5

Comment: You should look at moving to version 3(IMO) as it deals with multiple Servers, multiple roles,stages way better.    see my answer below (it is based on version 3 of capistrano)

Answer (score 0):

This should just work, but you should set up your ssh connections so you do not have to enter a password, using ssh keys.

Comment: Can you tell what is the correct syntax to set ssh keys for every ip?

Answer (score 0):

this is for for version 3,  and was posted before seeing version was set 2.

try setting your global options like this.

```
 set :ssh_options, {
   keys: %w(/home/your_user/.ssh/id_key),
   forward_agent: true,
  }
```

And is your key called id_key (id_rsa is more common)

if you need to do it per server you can do this.

```
server 'ip1', 
 user: 'root',
 roles: %w{web app},
 ssh_options: {
   user: 'foobar', # overrides user setting above
   keys: %w(/home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa),
   forward_agent: false,
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So 'footbar' should be 'debian' in my case, right?

Comment: well where are you deploying to /home/debian/apps/{application}?  basically  what you do is set all the common stuff in global configs, and then use the per server overrides to make changes on each server if needed (IE using different keys or different ssh options).  the user option there could be debian if you are logging into the server as debian@ip. Or are you trying deploy the app as root to /home/debian you would probably need to use a different user/name

Comment: I am confused because I log in with root@ip but my directory is /home/debian/apps/{application} So deploy_to should be the same with debian for all servers but the overrided user in ip1 should be root or debian?

Comment: if you do not need to dynamically set the deploy_to to. you can say `/home/debain/apps/Name`  and not worry about the overrides,  but that is off from your orig question, are you still getting auth failure,  I would try hardcoding path to your key, only if it is different from the user you are running cap deploy as)  if you can ssh root@ip1 directly from your user without specifying a key file, you can remote the ssh_keys options.